# Quaternion.LookRotation rotating AI character issue [UNITY 3D]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple AI Enemy and with a script to make the enemy face the player but I'm getting a weird result where the enemy rotates backwards the closer it gets to the player and when its next to the player it lays down almost flat.

This is my first time trying out AI so I'm not really sure what's wrong. I double checked to make sure the model was imported correctly and looked at the documentation for Quaternion.LookRotation and it seems to be the correct way to set it up. Any ideas on whats wrong is appreciated!

Heres the script:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform target;

private void Update()
{
    MoveToTarget();
}
private void MoveToTarget()
{
    agent.SetDestination(target.position);

    RotateToTarget();
}

private void RotateToTarget()
{
    
    Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.up);
    transform.rotation = rotation;

}
```

Comment: Is the transform point of the AI lower down than the players?

Comment: @JDormer Yes its lower than the players, I moved it to be higher than the players and it made it worse, any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest you try set the ai at the same height as the player, so there is no y difference on the direction vector.

Comment: @JDormer TY for the help, I wrote direction.y = 0 to ignore the y axis entirely and its working as intended now!

Answer (score 0):

`direction.y = 0;`

fixes it by ignoring the y axis entirely